# How do I use Xpath to locate parent node where a child node does not contain an attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

Using Xpath, how can I locate a parent element where none of multiple child elements contains a specific attribute value among a list of attribute values?

Here's a sample of my xml:

```
<app>
  <rdg wit="#R #W #I #S #C #O #D">existunt,</rdg>
  <rdg wit="#J">existant,</rdg>
</app>
```

My XML has hundreds of these  elements that should all have the same set of eight attribute values (#R, etc.) distributed variously among two or more  elements. But a few of the  are missing an attribute value on the list, and I need to locate those  nodes.

So I'm trying to find, say, all the `<app>` elements where *none of the child `<rdg>` elements* contains #R.

I can get the ones that *do* contain #R with `//app/rdg[contains(@wit,"#R")]` and I know there's a not() function, but I haven't figured out how to get these to work together.

Comment: have you tried this? `//app/rdg[not(contains(@wit,"#R"))]`

Comment: I had, and it doesn't work. This Xpath finds all the `<rdg>` elements without #R in them. In the sample above, therefore, it finds `<rdg wit="#J">existant,</rdg>`, which is not what I needed. There is at least one such line in every `<app>` element. I needed to find each `<app>` element that didn't include #R in *any* of its `<rdg>` elements, which means that it needed to skip the sample `<app>` above entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this as follows:

```
//app[not(rdg/@wit[contains(., '#R')])]
```

Alternatively:

```
//app[not(rdg[contains(@wit, '#R')])]
```

This slightly convoluted approach is necessary because the `app`s contain multiple `rdg`s, so we're basically doing (to take the second example):

- Select all `app`s where...
- There is not a `rdg` child where...
- The `wit` attribute contains `#R`